# Activerecord joining syntax. Square Brackets vs Curly Brackets?

Tags: activerecord

This is from the Rails docs:

> 12.1.3.2 Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)

```
Category.joins(articles: [{ comments: :guest }, :tags])
```

> This produces:

```
SELECT categories.* FROM categories
  INNER JOIN articles ON articles.category_id = categories.id
  INNER JOIN comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
  INNER JOIN guests ON guests.comment_id = comments.id
  INNER JOIN tags ON tags.article_id = articles.id
```

> Or, in English: "return all categories that have articles, where those articles have a comment made by a guest, and where those articles also have a tag."

So that all makes sense. But how do I get this sql in ActiveRecord:

```
SELECT categories.* FROM categories
      INNER JOIN articles ON articles.category_id = categories.id
      INNER JOIN comments ON comments.article_id = articles.id
      INNER JOIN guests ON guests.comment_id = comments.id
      INNER JOIN tags ON tags.comments_id = comments.id
```

How do I join `tags` back to `comments`. In english, I want:

> "return all categories that have articles, where those articles have a comment made by a guest, and where those comments also have a tag."

More importantly, what's a good way to think of curly vs square brackets?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Category.joins(articles: { comments: [:guest, :tag] })
```

Think of curly braces (hash) as nested conditions for a joined table.  Think of square braces (array) as means for joining multiple tables.